# How to install a System App on a rooted device?

Tags: android, apk

After 3 days of googling I am at my wits end witho no solution to this.

I have written a System app with System privileges (INSTALL_PACKAGE permission)  on android. It is a part of a firmware being developed.

Now I want to test it on my device. I am just not able to do it. I have a rooted device with android 4.2.2.

I tried installing an it by copying it on /system/app But its not showing as installed. I am using eclipse debug keys currently. Do i need to sign it with android signature keys?

I tried doing the same with other market apps and was able to install them as System app this way but not my own app.

Pls suggest.

Thanks

Comment: Does it generate an exception or just nothing happens ?

Comment: @pskink There is a thing called firmware. And there are serious coders coding for it. Its not just about games and viruses all the time. And when i say the device is rooted you should get the idea.

Comment: @Shivam I am using a rooted file manager app to install the app and no errors are shown on that

Comment: @couling As said its going to be used on a rooted device.if somebody is smart enough or dumb enough to keep his device rooted all the time he is not bothered about viruses in both cases.

Comment: @couling I have edited the question for clarity. Thanks for pointing it out.